# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined(PHP CON JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, php

estoy tratando de hacer un get a una etiqueta y luego colocarle un atributo pero me sale el error de Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined"

Este es mi código(lo estoy haciendo en PHP)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , ' var footer_text = document.getElementsByClassName("powered-by")[0];'
   , 'footer_text.setAttribute("id", "text");'
   , '</script>'
;
```

Si necesitan más información solo pidanmelo, gracias de ante mano

HTML:

```
<div class="powered-by">
                Funciona gracias a <a href="https://es.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a>.           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que tu etiqueta `<script>` aparezca en el cuerpo de la página arriba del elemento y puedes solucionarlo si el código se ejecuta hasta que el DOM se haya cargado.

Además, para evita concatenaciones y, de paso, hacer el código un poco más legible, puedes *"entrar en modo HTML"* y, al terminar, *"volver al modo PHP"*:

```
// Cambiar a modo HTML
?>
<script>
// Ejecutar hasta que el DOM se haya cargado
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Solo es un elemento, .querySelector es más apropiado y sencillo
    var footer_text = document.querySelector('.powered-by');
    // Modificar directamente ID del elemento
    footer_text.id = 'text';
});
</script>
<?php
// De vuelta en modo PHP
```

Finalmente, si quieres modificar o eliminar el mensaje, creo que lo más sencillo sería editar directamente la plantilla o usar una extensión. Creo que [este artículo](https://kinsta.com/es/base-de-conocimiento/remover-powered-by-wordpress/) te puede servir.

Comment: De hecho estoy practicando en hacer plugins, por eso lo de modificar el footer

Comment: Ahora pruebo eso y te digo, muchas gracias

Comment: FUNCIONO! MUCHAS GRACIAS